# How to use checkbox inside Dropdown?

Tags: flutter

I want  to add checkbox with dropdown menu items.For now I'm using a Row with check box and text inside DropdownMenuItem but i'm getting no change after clicking on checkbox.

Comment: Please provide some code!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work for you

```
bool isChecked=false;
DropdownButtonFormField(
items: [
DropdownMenuItem(
child: Row(
children: <Widget>[
StatefulBuilder(builder:
(BuildContext context,
StateSetter stateSetter) {
return Checkbox(
onChanged: (bool value) {
stateSetter(() {
_isChecked = value;
});
},
value: _isChecked,
);
}),
Text("label"),
```